# developing a linux driver for X server and custom display hardware

Tags: linux, arm, driver, xorg, xserver

I have asked this question at [unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/466381/write-linux-driver-for-x-server-and-custom-display-hardware) and got paradoxical answers through comments. so decided to ask it again here.

I am going to show Linux desktop environment on a LCD connected to a zynq board with ARM Cortex A9 processor. My idea is to write a driver for its Linux that sends desktop environment displaying data from X server to my hardware.

How can I write driver for kernel interacting with X server and my own hardware to show linux desktop environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way of doing this will be to write [a fbdev (framebuffer device)](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/fb/framebuffer.txt) driver for your system. Xorg already supports framebuffer devices, so it will be able to use your display with no modifications; as a bonus, the Linux console can use the framebuffer too.

Comment: thank you for your response.
yes, frame buffer can be used for displaying. but how can I get desktop environment displaying data?

Comment: By running a desktop environment. That part has nothing to do with the drivers.

Comment: desktop environment runs on X server, right? should not I drive desktop displaying data from there to my own display hardware?

Comment: how desktop displaying can drive to my LCD through frame buffer?

Comment: The X server will write pixel data to the fb device. Your driver would take that pixel data and show it on the LCD.

Comment: @thatotherguy yes I got it. thank you for your attention :)